# Pass functions e^(-x) and e^(-x^2) into a function for computation in C

Tags: c, exp

I have to write a program that passes the functions `e^(-x)` and `e^(-x^2)` into another function, called `calculateIntegral()`, which will then calculate the integral of the function.

Restrictions:

- `calculateIntegral()` is the function which will be used to compute the integral of both `e^(-x)` and `e^(-x^2)`
- I can only have the function passed, the `a` and `b` bounds, and the number of intervals as the arguments for function `calculateIntegral()`.

I've thought about changing `x` to, say, `-x` outside the function and assigning it to another variable to compute in `e^(x)`, but then I would have to include that as another argument in `calculateIntegral()`.

Is there any way to alter the original `e^(x)`, so that when it gets passed into `calculateIntegral()`, it would be `e^(-x)` so the rest function would just have to plug the bounds into that equation for calculations?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to parametrize the integrand, so you want to be able to pass the function that `f` has to integrate as a parameter. In C, this can be done with *function pointers*:

```
// IntegrandT now is the type of a pointer to a function taking a double and
// returning a double
typedef double (*IntegrandT)(double);

// The integration function takes the bound and the integrand function
double f(double min, double max, IntegrandT integrand)
{
    // here integrand will be called as if it were a "normal" function
}

// Your example functions
double minusExp(double x)
{
    return exp(-x);
}

double unitaryGaussian(double x)
{
    return exp(-x*x);
}

// now you can do
double res=f(-10, 10, minusExp);
double res2=f(-10, 10, unitaryGaussian);
```

For more details about function pointers, check your C manual.